# InvalidAuthenticationToken while using Microsoft Graph

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, passport.js, openid-connect, passport-azure-ad

I've a Node.js API which is authenticated using passport and passport-azure-ad's OIDC strategy.

After User's authentication I get User's profile, access_token, refresh_token, sub and ISS.

Then I use the same access_token to get User's details from Microsoft graph using this API - https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me

When I request, it prompts me this error,

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "InvalidAuthenticationToken",
        "message": "Access token validation failure.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "04048b3a-7636-4197-88ef-1f08d3a07c9e",
            "date": "2018-12-26T09:40:58"
        }
    }
}
```

When I use OAuth 2.0 and get the access_token and use that access_token to access the same API, the details are returned successfully.

Although even I tried matching the access_tokens returned by Open ID connect and OAuth 2.0, they differ despite logging in as a same user.

I don't understand why the access_token returned by the Open ID connect didn't worked.

Comment: What was the `resource` you used when acquiring a token? That says which API you want to call. If you specify `resource=https://graph.microsoft.com`, then you'll get one for MS Graph API.

Comment: @juunas Can you suggest me a way to handle this authentication and authorization if I'm using react native and node.js api, because I cannot get the cookie in the react app since its not in the web view.
Can you tell me a way to use AAD and Node.js API integraton?

Comment: You need to acquire an access token for your API in your React Native app and pass it in the Authorization header on all requests to the API. The API then needs to implement JWT authentication. There should not be cookies sent to the API.

Comment: Will this JWT authentication validate the same access token which is provided by the OAuth provider to React Native Client? If yes then how can I validate the JWT token sent from the header by react native client?
Is there any method in passport.js?

Earlier I've used req.isAuthenticated() method to check the authentication

Comment: I want to make an API which will act like Microsoft graph, I want to know the method of Microsoft Graph used to validate the token.
The same thing I've to implement in my Node.js API

Comment: I've seen a library's method, JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateToken Method (JwtSecurityToken) but this is for .NET framework, I want this kind of library for Node.js